# WooCommerce Customer Order xml export suite plugin

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I using the woocommerce-customer-order-xml-export-suite plugin and trying to customize the output xml. I have if 90% figured out, it the last part that is giving me issues. Basically the output xml has to look like this:

Order.xml

```
            <ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="1">
                <ItemID>
                    <SupplierPartID>GPS-2215RB</SupplierPartID>
                </ItemID>
                <ItemDetail>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money currency="USD">105.99</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                </ItemDetail>
            </ItemOut>
        </OrderRequest>
    </Request>
</cXML>
```

This is what I am getting now:

MyOrder.xml

```
            <ItemOut Quantity="">
                <ItemID>
                    <SupplierPartID>S1072-35</SupplierPartID>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                </ItemID>
                <ItemDetail>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <SupplierPartID>S1072-35</SupplierPartID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </UnitPrice>
                </ItemDetail>
            </ItemOut>
        </OrderRequest>
    </Request>
</cXML>
```

Here is my current PHP code:

```
                        'ItemOut'       => array(
                            '@attributes'   => array('Quantity' => $item_data['qty'] ),
                            'ItemID'       => wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ),
                            'ItemDetail'        => array(
                                    'UnitPrice' => wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ),
                                ),
                            ),

                    ), // End OrderRequest Array
                ), //End Main Request Array
            ), // End Request

    );
}
add_filter( 'wc_customer_order_xml_export_suite_order_export_order_list_format', 'wc_sample_xml_order_list_format', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Adjust the individual line item format
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @param object $order \WC_Order instance
 * @return array
 */
function wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ) {

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {

        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item_data );

        $ItemID[] = array(
            'SupplierPartID'    => $product->get_sku(),
            'Quantity'          => $item_data['qty'],
        );
        $ItemDetail[] = array(
            'Money'             => $product->get_price(),
        );
    }

    return $ItemID;

}
```

Here is the last part of the php code that I'm having issues with. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest minimizing your code and snippets to isolate the parts that you already have working from the parts that are not working. It is less overhead for people who are trying to help out. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, I removed the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so both your ItemID and ItemDetail/UnitPrice are showing the same thing because they are calling the same function, `wc_sample_xml_get_line_items`. The returned value of that function is saved in your array:

```
'ItemOut' => array(
    '@attributes' => array('Quantity' => $item_data['qty'] ),
    'ItemID'      => wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ),
    'ItemDetail'  => array(
        'UnitPrice'   => wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ),
    ),
```

The result of that function is the return value,

```
function wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ) {
    <...snipped irrelevant stuff...>
        $ItemID[] = array(
            'SupplierPartID'    => $product->get_sku(),
            'Quantity'          => $item_data['qty'],
        );
        $ItemDetail[] = array(
            'Money'             => $product->get_price(),
        );
    }

    return $ItemID; # This is what's returned
}
```

I suspect that you want `$ItemDetail` to also be returned to be set in `UnitPrice`, but what is actually happening is that you've created `$ItemDetail`, however, once the function finishes, that variable is gone because it is not passed as a return value...and your function already has a return value for something else.

What you need is a new function that is similar to the first, but returns the money detail instead of the ItemID details:

```
function wc_sample_xml_get_line_item_unit_prices( $order ) {

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {

        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item_data );

        $ItemDetail[] = array(
            'Money'             => $product->get_price(),
        );
    }

    return $ItemDetail;    
}
```

And then you can use that for when creating your array:

```
'ItemOut' => array(
    '@attributes' => array('Quantity' => $item_data['qty'] ),
    'ItemID'      => wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ),
    'ItemDetail'  => array(
        'UnitPrice'   => wc_sample_xml_get_line_item_unit_prices( $order ),
),
```

EDIT:

**Getting ItemOut Output**

To get ItemOut to generate the XML you need, it is probably best to scrap `wc_sample_xml_get_line_item_unit_prices` and create one function that will generate the entirety of ItemOut, instead of doing it in bits in pieces. Here is what the resulting `ItemOut` assignment would look like:

```
'ItemOut' => wc_sample_xml_get_item_out( $order ),
```

Notice all the ItemId, ItemDetails, and all that are gone. We want to create that in `wc_sample_xml_get_item_out`. So, here is that:

```
function wc_sample_xml_get_line_items( $order ) {
    $itemOut = array ();

    // Keep track of the line Item number
    $lineNumber = 1;

    // Build a list of itemOut's from the line items in the order
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {  
        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item_data );

        // The idea here is that we'll generate each XML child node individually, then combine them into one ItemOut node afterwards.

        // So these will go in <itemout>'s attributes
        $newAttributes = array(
            'quantity'   => $item_data['qty'],
            'lineNumber' => $lineNumber
        );

        // This is ItemId
        $newItemId = array(
            'SupplierPartID' => $product->get_sku()
        );

        // and ItemDetail
        $newItemDetail = array (
            'UnitPrice' => array (
                'Money' => $product->get_price()
            )
        );

        // Now we combine these into the ItemOut
        $newItemOut = array(
            '@attributes' => $newAttributes,
            'ItemId'      => $newItemId,
            'itemDetail'  => $newItemDetail
        );

        // Now we tack this new item out onto the array
        $itemOut[] = $newItemOut;

        // Set the next line number, and then loop until we've done each line item
        $lineNumber++;
    }
    return $itemOut;
}
```

I am pretty sure that will get you there or very close. Since I don't have access to your $order and $item_data and even OrderRequest, I'm not sure that it will be structured correctly when you have multiple line items in an order. If this works, definitely test an order with multiple line items and tweak as necessary.

Comment: Hope this answer doesn't come off of as condescending, but I am trying to make the answer as clear as possible.

Comment: That works, and it did not come off as condescending. Another question, how do I get the quantity and line number to show up in the attributes?

<ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="1">

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the answer, adding a new section on how to do that. It's a bit more work, but worthwhile.

Comment: Hey thanks for the edits, the $lineNumber++; is throwing this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$lineNumber' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Left out a semicolon missing from the previous statement... $itemOut[] = $newItemOut. In the future, if syntax errors are bugging you, try copy-and-pasting into a website like http://phpcodechecker.com.

Comment: Oops, there are several errors: 1. make sure there are no semicolons inside the array definitions, 2. was missing a semicolon as I mentioned in last comment.